# Создать блок css

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте,помогите пожалуйста создать блок на css вот такого вида : 
http://hkar.ru/qRTE
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я, честно говоря, с трудом представляю себе какие-то затруднения http://jsfiddle.net/y4jZ9/

Comment: @Fike,спасибо)

Comment: @Fike,только нужно сделать этот блок с линиями белого цвета по бокам.Типо обводка.

Comment: @Fike,вот так должен выглядеть блок.Черный цвет это считай прозрачный. http://cs540108.vk.me/c608028/v608028641/4485/kbZ1LejbU64.jpg 
Спасибо.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xX4eD/

Answer (score 1):

все просто http://jsfiddle.net/xX4eD/

```css
.wrap {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 390px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.top-block {
    min-height: 80px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.bottom-block {
    margin-top: 5px;
    min-height: 700px;
    background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="top-block"></div>
    <div class="bottom-block"></div>
</div>
```